# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes)

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, memory

Running a Wordpress 6.2 site with php 7.4, nginx

I get:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in /var/www/pharmatrust.ca/htdocs/wp-includes/script-loader.php on line 1029

I tried:

1. changing my php.ini memory_limit = 1024M (I tried various values)
2. changing my wp-config by adding define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M') (I tried various values)
3. I removed my plugins and it didn't change anything

The website was properly working previously
Can't even access my admin.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you restart the webserver after changing the setting in php.ini?
Maybe try even more than 1024M.

Comment: This typically happens if you have some infinite loop somewhere, eating up the memory.

Comment: Yes I restarted the server. I installed another theme and the error went away. I suspect the theme had an infinite loop!

Answer (score 0):

Finally installed manually a theme on Wordpress and changed the theme on the database. The error is now gone. It was a theme error and possibly an infinite loop.